# Example of how to do TODO Filtering in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

So I am trying to figure out how to filter my TODO list as when I look at it now it has 527 most of which are in my included libraries.  I looked at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/defining-todo-patterns-and-filters.html) but really felt I needed an example.

I would like to be able to put in my code something like this:

```
//TODO name
```

Then when I bring up the TODO tab be able to see just those one.

Comment: Did you read the documentation under "To define a filter that will be used to show specific types of TODO items?"

Comment: Yes but some how it didn't click till I found the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an example in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/todo-example.html).

basically I need to create a pattern:

```
\btodo name\b.*
```

Then create a filter and choose that pattern.

[image]